# Django Matplotlib Animation embed in templates

Tags: django, animation, matplotlib, django-templates, django-views

Hi so I am using matplot lib in my django project. And I am able to embed a graph in my template/webpage. I need some help now on being able to animate a graph.

The graph is stored as a csv file with the location in my model. I want the graphs to be built dynamically. Now I have that. But I want them to be an animation. How would I go about doing this? I have to use matplotlib btw.

I assume make a video? I've seen people embed videos, but I was hoping to using the actual animation features of matplotlib such as:

http://pythonprogramming.net/python-matplotlib-live-updating-graphs/

Here is how I render the graph in my view:

```
def render_graph(request, graph_id=None):
    graph = get_object_or_404(models.Graph, pk=graph_id) #grabs actual graph
    data = np.genfromtxt(graph.data, delimiter=',', names=['x','y']) #extract data from cvs after x and y

    fig = Figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    ax.plot(data['x'], data['y'], label=graph.name)
    canvas=FigureCanvas(fig)

    response = HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')

    canvas.print_png(response)
    return(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

have you considered using d3 (d3js.org)? Might give better results.

Comment: HAVE to use matplotlib.